# Alterar propriedades do prompt de comando no c

Tags: c, cmd

Sou novato na linguagem c. Gostaria de saber se é possível alterar propriedades do prompt de comando pelo c, como tamanho do cmd,largura ou mesmo a fonte?

Comment: Você pode ser mais específico? Quer alterar via programação, você tem o código fonte do cmd?

Comment: gostaria de altera-lo via programação tipo aumentar o layout ou mudar a fonte algo do tipo

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que compreendi, você terá que alterar estas propriedades no registro do Windows. Para cada propriedade há um valor DWORD. Muito cuidado ao alterar estes valores, algum dado inválido pode acabar corrompendo e comprometendo o sistema operacional. Antes de alterar você terá que fazer uma conversão de dados para hexadecimal. A chave do registro responsável por estas propriedades é a: **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console**.

Se você ainda não tem idéia de como fazer isso em linguagem C, segue um link de um tutorial que possa lhe ajudar:

[Adicionar/Excluir e Ler Registro do Windows em C#, simples e direto.](https://franckepeixoto.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/adicionarexcluir-e-ler-registro-do-windows-em-c-simples-e-direto/)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar códigos para cores:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define RED   "\x1B[31m"
#define GRN   "\x1B[32m"
#define YEL   "\x1B[33m"
#define BLU   "\x1B[34m"
#define MAG   "\x1B[35m"
#define CYN   "\x1B[36m"
#define WHT   "\x1B[37m"
#define RESET "\x1B[0m"

int main()
{
  printf(RED "vermelho\n" RESET);
  printf(GRN "verde\n" RESET);
  printf(YEL "amarelo\n" RESET);
  printf(BLU "azul\n" RESET);
  printf(MAG "magenta\n" RESET);
  printf(CYN "ciano\n" RESET);
  printf(WHT "branco\n" RESET);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Acho que o que ele procura é uma forma de alterar as propriedades da janela, não apenas a fonte

Comment: Antes do Windows 10, acho, o prompt de comando do Windows não aceita sequências de escape ISO 6429 ("ANSI")...